# Which is the easy way to build login/registration/admin area type website in java

Tags: java, wicket

I am php programmer but i am learning java now. i have finished the core java and build small projects using jdbc , mysql gui etc.

Now my boss wants to build the website where user will collect points  and they can shop based upon points left.

But the initial phase will be only the logs/registration/admin area etc.

Now i have two options

1)Do in php
2)DO in java

I really want to do in java thats why i was learning it. Now now the project came early.
I wanted to learn  spring , spring mvc , hibernate etc , design patterns but now i can't spend time first to learn.

i want to ask that what will be good solution to go at it. Initially was thinking of doing the website in JSP.Is that ok

O i am thinking of using Wicket and not using hibernate, is wicket enough to build ecommerce site. or i need anything else as well

I know only core java , what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP development is very action/template-oriented, AFAIK. Wicket is a component-based framework, that heavily applies object-orientation concepts, and that may take some time to grasp. If you don't have much experience with OO, and your deadlines are tight, maybe you'll prefer an action-framework (Struts2, SpringMVC), which is far better than raw JSP. But, if you have some time to spend, and the will to learn, Wicket is definitely a great framework!

Spring is also nice, and while dependency injection is not something you see often in PHP, it's simple enough (Spring is well documented, its reference doc is actually useful, and you'll find many tutorials and examples on the Internet), and it's definitely worth learning.

Hibernate is a very good framework for persistence, but if all you know is plain SQL/JDBC, it takes some time to master it to the point that you don't get frustrated with mapping, and lazy-loading errors. Again, try it if you have some time to spare and the will to learn.

Wicket+Spring+Hibernate is a really nice combo, I use them a lot. It may or may not be the best stack for your case. As everything in IT, it depends on the context. But I think they are very sound technologies, individually or combined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Struts 2.  It is both effective and there is a good size community here if you have any questions.  I don't know wicket, but any web framework is better than straight JSP.

Hibernate is nice but since you have a lot on your plate you should probably stick with straight JDBC for now. Spring is also very nice, it is easy to integrate spring DI with struts2 (so easy as a matter of fact I would recommend you just start that way).

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways to get a Java webapp up and running is to use [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).